# what does it mean "a column functionally depend on another column"?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Regarding this error:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'classicmodels.oe.phone' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

When we select the nonaggreated column, it has to be either in group by clause or functionally depend on the group by columns.

What does it mean by a column "functionally depend on" another column?

```
with oe as (
    select    o.officeCode, o.phone, e.employeeNumber 
    from      offices o 
    left join employees e
           on o.officeCode = e.officeCode
)
select   count(*), phone 
from     oe 
group by officeCode
```

I use the classicmodels sample database from [mysqltutorial.org](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx):

[image]

The above query is fine, even when I list the column `phone`, but group by the column `officeCode`.

But if I do not use the CTE, but:

```
create table oe as 
    select    o.officeCode, o.phone, e.employeeNumber 
    from      offices o 
    left join employees e
           on o.officeCode = e.officeCode;
```

and then:

```
select   count(*), phone 
from     oe 
group by officeCode
```

I would get the error:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'classicmodels.oe.phone' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Does it mean that in the above CTE version, column `phone` is functionally depending on `officeCode`, so we are ok to list column `phone` while we group by column `officeCode`?

What other use cases of a column is functionally depending on another column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I do not use the CTE, but `create table...` I would get the error

This is because in the new table, `officeCode` is not defined as unique (by index / primary key), and therefore `phone` cannot be considered as functional dependent from it.

> Does it mean that in the above CTE version, column `phone` is functionally depending on `officeCode`, so we are ok to list column `phone` while we group by column `officeCode`?

Yes.

> What other use cases of a column is functionally depending on another column?

The MySQL reference manual lists several cases at [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html):

> The following discussion provides several examples [...]:
>
> - Functional Dependencies Derived from Keys
> - Functional Dependencies Derived from Multiple-Column Keys and from Equalities
> - Functional Dependency Special Cases
> - Functional Dependencies and Views
> - Combinations of Functional Dependencies

I will not cite the whole article, and invite readers to visit this article in the reference manual.